Why does UV matrix factorization for recommender systems work?
In recommender systems research one approach is to make a UV matrix factorization.
$M' = U\cdot V$
where the number of columns of $U$ equals the number of rows of $V$ and "$\cdot$" is the matrix product.
$M$ has a has a lot of missing values and we minimize $||M-M'||$.
Here, we use the Frobenius distance over the non-missing values of $M$.
My understanding is that idea is that we are effectively projecting all users and items into a relatively low dimensional space, for example 2 dimensional.
And then we use the dot product as a similarity measure.
Here is where it breaks down for me: If someone likes feature A and dislikes feature B, they would have a preference vector (in the 2 dimensional space) of (5,1). If an item has those features (or absence thereof), then we have a $5^2+1^2=26$ similarity. However, if the preference vector is (1,1) and the item has the same features (1,1) then the similarity is 2. And if the two vectors are (5,5) and (5,5), then the similarity is 50. However, that means that these are under- or over-considered in the cost function $||M-M'||$. Namely, the (1,1)-pair is under-considered and the (5,5)-pair is over-considered.
(By the way: I do not see how using the cosine-similarity would improve here too much: Using it would mean that (1,1) has the same similarity to (1,1) as to (5,5), which makes no sense.)
I also read they are dimensionality reducing, but I do not see what dimension is reduced to what here.
My question is: Why does UV matrix factorization for recommender systems work, considering the issue I wrote.
